# How to sort objects in arrayList by their class?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` that holds 2 types of objects in it (objects from class `Student` and objects from class `Teacher`).

My question is how can I sort it so that all objects that are from `Student` to appear first and then all objects that are from class `Teacher` to appear after them.

For example: Student1, Student2, Student3, Teacher1,Teacher2,Teacher3

Here is my code:

```
public ArrayList sortList(){

    ArrayList<Student> students = new  ArrayList<Student>();
    ArrayList<Teacher> teachers = new  ArrayList<Teacher>();
    ArrayList<Person> university = new  ArrayList<Person>();
    for(Person p : list){
        if(p.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("Teacher")){
            teachers.add((Teacher)p);
        };
        if(p.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("Student")){
            students.add((Student)p);
        }
        university.addAll(students);
        university.addAll(teachers);
    }
    return university;
}
```

Comment: Did you read about "Comparable" in java?

Comment: While we don't know the context, I would like to generally advice to just keep students and teachers in two separate ArrayLists. We all know that having both in the same class room is already problematic, but the same ArrayList? Oh boy.

Comment: Well, dirty solution might be to run for loop and check with instanceof keyword.

Comment: If you really need to have them both in one list, then you can separate into two list sort each list, and then append one list to the other

Comment: Read up comparator and comparable.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Collections.sort(list,comparator)`

In the Comparator you can compare the class names because (luckily) `S` is before `T` in the alphabet:

```
   List<Object> studentsAndTeachers = // ...
   Collections.sort(studentsAndTeachers, (o1, o2) -> o1.getClass().getName().compareTo(o2.getClass().getName()));
```

of cause you ave to apply other sorting criteria first or extend the comparator to recognize them...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Comparator.comparing` for that:

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Teacher.class::isInstance))
```

This works because `Class.isInstance` returns `boolean` which is wrapped into `Boolean` which implements `Comparable`.

Comment: Or, if you want to sort on class name: `Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparing(o -> o.getClass().getName()))`

Answer (score 0):

Now it should work like a bread with butter:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Human> humans = new ArrayList<>();
        humans.add(new Teacher("Teacher1"));
        humans.add(new Teacher("Teacher2"));
        humans.add(new Student("Student3"));
        humans.add(new Student("Student1"));
        humans.add(new Teacher("Teacher3"));
        humans.add(new Student("Student2"));

        Collections.sort(humans, new Comparator<Human>()
        {
            @Override
            public int compare(Human o1, Human o2)
            {
                if (o2 instanceof Teacher) {
                    return -1;
                } else if (o1 instanceof Teacher && o2 instanceof Student) {
                    return 1;
                }
                /* other checks not about being teacher or student goes here... */                
            }
        });
        System.out.println(humans);
    }
}

interface Human
{
    String getName();

    void setName(String name);
}

class Teacher implements Human
{
    private String name;

    public Teacher(String name)
    {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class Student implements Human
{
    private String name;

    public Student(String name)
    {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: The comparable interface should maintain the *natural order* of object of a class. My feeling is that being *Teacher* or *Student* is not the *natural order* of persons (at least not in *that* order... ;o) )

Answer (score 0):

Sorting like this will do the job for you, although is not a quite good solution generally speaking.

```
Collections.sort(classroom, (o1, o2) -> {
    if (o1 instanceof Student && o2 instanceof Teacher) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (o1 instanceof Teacher && o2 instanceof Student) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `Comparator` class that orders `Human` objects based on class name, and then the value of the name attribute.

```
    public class Comparator<Human> {
        public int compare(Human h1, Human h2) {
            int res = h1.getClass().getName().compareTo(
                         h2.getClass().getName());
            if (res == 0) {
                res = h1.getName().compareTo(h2.getName());
            }
            return res;
        }
    }
```

If you use this with `Collections.sort(...)`, you can sort the list into the required order.

Note that this implementation:

- sorts objects with the same type based on their name (as implied by the example), and
- doesn't break if you add more subclasses of `Human`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Comparator.comparing` along with `listName.sort()` like below;

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(o -> o.getClass().getName()));
```